# How to save base64 json file coming from server in Mobile External storage?

Tags: android, file

I am getting a base64 string from server in json response.It may contain image,zip file,pdf,mp3 or video.If i am going to decode the base 64 string then in the imageview the image is showing,but i want to download the file and open it in mobile gallery in case if it is image,if it is pdf it will open in pdf reader like that....how to achieve this?

```
"attach":[{"id":6,"name":"Ticket.pdf","thread_id":17,"size":"356660","type":"application\/pdf","poster":"ATTACHMENT","created_at":"2018-03-13 11:40:32","updated_at":"2018-03-13 11:40:32","file":"base64 encoded string","driver":"local","path":"\/home\/jamboree\/public_html\/sayarnew\/storage\/app\/private\/2018\/3\/13"}]
```

Comment: first of all  you have to check whether it is pdf , image , zip file .... according to your type , you can easily open your file  by simple  if else  condition

Comment: Hi Tejas , suppose it is a image can you post some code regarding this...

Comment: `How to download base 64 file from server?`. Badly worded problem. You are downloading json from server.

Comment: @greenapps yes you are right...

Comment: Well... why dont you change the subject?

Comment: Is it possible to create uri from that json  response?

Comment: You still have a pretty bad subject. Please try better. Thesubjectshould describe your problem or what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the field from your endpoint, check whether it is an image/pdf. Since you said you can show it imageview, you may have bitmap. Convert this bitmap to file and store it in your memory(hence download of image is done) . See below code to convert bitmap to file and store in memory

```
private void downLoadImage(Bitmap bitmap) {

String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
File directory = new File(path + "/dir_images");    
directory.mkdirs();
Random generator = new Random();
int n = 10000;
n = generator.nextInt(n);
String fname = "IM_"+ n +".jpg";
File file = new File (directory, fname);
if (file.exists ())
  file.delete (); 
try {
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
    out.flush();
    out.close();

} catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you get is `"name":"Ticket.pdf"` and   `type":"application\/pdf"`. This gives you the file name and extension you can use.

```
 ,"file":"base64 encoded string",
```

Just base64 decode that string and save resulting bytes to file using a file name and extension.

So the first step is saving all to the file system.

After that you use `ACTION_VIEW` to open files in suitable apps.

Comment: can you post some more explanation here.....i will save the file and then i want to open that particular file using intent......

Comment: i have decoded the string and convert into bytes and stored into file system.But after this i want to open that file using intent,suppose the file is image so if i click on button it should open in the gallery.

Comment: No it will not automatically open in gallery. If you use ACTION_VIEW then you let the user choose which app to use to show an image or pdf.

Comment: How to use ACTION_VIEW for a pdf Mohit Hooda already told you. The rest he told is nonsense. But you can use the code he posted for a pdf for an image too if you change the mime type.

Comment: Is it possible to create uri from that json response?